# Trying to return true or false from an authentification function with node

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function that should return true or false. I know for sure that in this case it should return true but a console.log displays " Promise { pending }".

Here is the function :

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const sqlConfig = {
    
    user: accessDB.DB_USER,
    password: accessDB.DB_PWD,
    database: accessDB.DB_NAME,
  server: accessDB.SERVER,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: false, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  }
}
const authentification = async (login, password) => {

var sqls = `SELECT CLICOD FROM Clients WHERE CLICOD = '${login}' AND PasswordFtp ='${password}'`

 try {

  await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
  const result = await sql.query(sqls)

if (result.rowsAffected > 0) {
    return true;
}else {
    return false;
}

 } catch (err) {
console.log(err)
 }
}
module.exports = authentification;
```

This next part of the code is supposed to receive the result (true or false) but always ends up in the "not authorized" section even though a console.log of the result.rowsAffected does return 1.

```
app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
 
if (authentification(req.query.login, req.query.pass)===true) {

  res.send("authorized");
}else {
  res.send("not authorized");
}

})
```

Can an async function return a result at all?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: is there a reason you are using it as a function and not a middleware?

Comment: I think the reason is that my comprehension of the concept is weak! How would you resolve the problem?

Comment: Express's power lies with middlewares, it's like gates, and you can have as many gates as you like, for example logging in is the first gate (your first middleware) if the user credentials are correct you allow him to the next request using `return next()` if his information are wrong you can throw error or `res.status(403).json({msg:"not allowed})`

i'd familiarize with the concept first, once it clicks it will make writing express apps much better for you https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll definitively explore the concept.

Answer (score 0):

change your route function to async and await for `authentification` response like below:

```
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
  const isAuthenticated = await authentification(req.query.login, req.query.pass)
  if (isAuthenticated === true) {

    res.send("authorized");
  } else {
    res.send("not authorized");
  }

})
```

Comment: it doesn't like it  : "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: i updated the answer, removed the parentheses in if

Comment: Unfortunately it still crahes with the same notification.

Comment: can you share the whole error message? or which line you get the error?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47`

Comment: error is on this line :` if (await authentification(req.query.login, req.query.pass) === true)`

Comment: i updated the answer, not sure why this syntax is not working here

Comment: It's not working either, I get :"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: make sure you have `async` before your `(req, res)`

Comment: Ok! it works! great site, great people!  Thank you so much! coding rocks!

Comment: yw, if this answered your question mark it as answered, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does seem like an async/await problem. To await a condition that takes time to execute, you must use the await command before the function call. In order to use the await command, you must dignify the function the await is inside of to 'async'. This is how I would do it:

```js
app.get('/test',async (req,res)=>{
    const isAuthenticated = await authentification(req.query.login, req.query.pass);

    if (isAuthenticated===true) {
      res.send("authorized");
    }else {
      res.send("not authorized");
    }
})
```